# Trying to create a palindrome function that accounts for spaces

Tags: javascript, arrays

Okay so palindrome is a word that is the same spelled backwards. What if we want to take a phrase that is also the same backwards? So `kook` is one. `race car` is another one.

So I made one that doesn't account for spaces.

```
function isPal(string){
    var l = string.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < (l/2); ++i) {
        if (string.charAt(i) != string.charAt(l - i - 1)){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

This one works fine for words.

Now I'm thinking, push the string into an array, and split up each character into it's own string, then remove any spaces, and then run `if (string.charAt(i) != string.charAt(string.length - i - 1))`. So here's what I wrote but failed at..

```
function isPalindrome(string){
    var arr = [];
    arr.push(string.split(''));
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if (arr[i] === ' '){
            arr.splice(i, 1);
```

if I return `arr`, it still gives me the string with the space in it. How do I accomplish this? Thanks!

EDIT: Used the solution but still getting false on 'race car'
Here's what I got:

```
function isPalindrome(string){
    var arr = string.split('');
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if (arr[i] === ' '){
            arr.splice(i, 1);
        } else if (arr[i] != arr[arr.length - i - 1]){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

where's my error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in the following line:

```
arr.push(string.split(''));
```

string.split('') returns an array. So, arr is actually an array with one entry it in (another array that contains your characters). Replace:

```
var arr = [];
arr.push(string.split(''));
```

with

```
var arr = string.split('');
```

and it should work as expected

Comment: still getting false :( here's what I did...                                                                                                function isPalindrome(string){
    var arr = string.split('');
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if (arr[i] === ' '){
            arr.splice(i, 1);
        } else if (arr[i] != arr[arr.length - i - 1]){
         return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

Comment: Imagine you're running this on 'race car', your code hits the 'e' in before it hits the space. So, it goes to the else if and matches 'e' with ' ' and returns false.

Try running your code on 'r acecar' and it will return true. It will work as long as the space is before the halfway point of the string.

My advice is to strip spaces before checking for palindromes. It also generally considered a bad idea to modify the length of an array (by removing items) inside a loop that it is iterating through that array.

Answer (score 1):

Just check check the string without spaces:

```
function isPal(string){
   string = string.split(" ").join("");  // remove all spaces
   var l = string.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < (l/2); ++i) {
        if (string.charAt(i) != string.charAt(l - i - 1)){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

isPal("a man a plan a canal panama"); // true
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems much easier to just split into an array, reverse and join again to check if a word is a palindrome. If you want to ignore spaces, just remove all instances of spaces:

```
let word = 'race car';

let isPalindrome = (word) => {
   let nospaces = word.replace(/\s/g, '');
   return [...nospaces].reverse().join('') === nospaces;
}
```

Or non-es6:

```
var word = 'race car';

var isPalindrome = function(word) {
   var nospaces = word.replace(/\s/g, '');
   return nospaces.split('').reverse().join('') === nospaces;
}
```